# Making a YouTube video from powerpoint presentation file with embedded audio file

Tags: video-editor, video-quality

I have a power point type file (.odp in ubuntu linux) with embedded audio file in it for presentation. How can I make a good quality YouTube video from that? I have used kazam screen recorder for that. The video resolution looks good but after uploading it in YouTube the resolution get worser.

Comment: Is that an Open Office file?

Comment: It is "LibreOffice Impress" file.

Comment: Mmm I have a similar problem using Kazam screen recorder. When I save the video on my computer as MP4 it looks great. When I upload it to YouTube it's out of focus and clearly has lost quite a bit of it's resolution. Kazam is quite outdated but on Linux I couldn't get anything else working. Kazam has MP4 H264 and WebM VP8 and then it's also possible to set the frame rate. I would like to know what is the best for YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83

1. On the File menu, select Save to ensure all your recent work has
   been saved in PowerPoint presentation format (.pptx).
2. Click File >
   Export > Create a Video. (Or, on the Recording tab of the ribbon,
   click Export to Video.)
3. ...

Comment: It is a PowerPoint "like" file, not PowerPoint.

Comment: It is "LibreOffice Impress" file.